# Openlayers 3 print map div

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

Is there a native way to print the "map" div?

I've tried a couple different approaches...

```
var printContents =  document.getElementById("map").outerHTML;
                    var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=600,height=300');
                    popupWin.document.open();
                    popupWin.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" /></head><body onload="window.print()">' + printContents + '</body></html>');
                    popupWin.document.close();
```

And also...

```
var divContents = $("#map").html();
                    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
                    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
                    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
                    printWindow.document.write(divContents);
                    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
                    printWindow.document.close();
                    printWindow.print();
```

Both of these open a browser print window but both have a blank preview, it seems the code is finding the "map" div but not able to get the full HTML or something?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by locating the canvas element in the map div. If I use the map [here](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/simple.html), I can access the canvas by doing:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("map").getElementsByClassName("ol-unselectable")[0];
```

Next, convert it to an image object:

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Then, you can print the image on the page and print the page:

```
document.write('<img src="'+img+'"/>');
```

Comment: This is export to png. This is not print functionality.

Comment: Also we have the CORS problem